# Error with my implementation of the singleton pattern

Tags: java, singleton

I testing an implementation of the singleton pattern and I feel like I can't figure out why IntelliJ is throwing me an error. Here is the code.

```
public class CowSingleton {
    private static CowSingleton unique;
    private CowSingleton(){}

    //Only create new object if NOT already instantiated.

    public static CowSingleton getInstance(){
        if (unique == null){
            //creating unique object
            unique = new CowSingleton();
            System.out.println(unique);
        }
        //return Object
        return unique;
    }

    public String cowMoo(String str)
    {
       return str;
    }
}
```

And here is where how I'm calling it:

```
CowSingleton cowSingleton = new CowSingleton.getInstance();
System.out.println(cowSingleton.cowMoo("Moooooo"));
```

The error I'm getting:

```
"java: /Users/gpendleton/Personal/MyAnimals/src/Main.java:25: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class getInstance
location: class CowSingleton"
```

Comment: Why the use of `new`?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with IntelliJ.

Comment: I knew it was not because of ItelliJ, I'll make sure to check my wording next time.

Comment: `getInstance` is `static`. Call it via the class name directly. No need to create a object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not creating the instance yourself; you are deferring to the singleton class itself to  create it for you.  Your code that calls `getInstance()` does not need the `new` keyword.  After all, you are calling a static method, not creating an object yourself.

Remove the `new` keyword.

```
CowSingleton cowSingleton = CowSingleton.getInstance();
```

Comment: This helped, and thanks for the explanation. Helped me understand the error completely.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct - however this implementation of the Singleton pattern is horribly flawed and will break in unexpected ways in a multi-threading environment.

The easiest way is not to have lazy initialization of the singleton, if you really must have lazy initialization then do it using a static holder:

```
public class CowSingleton {

    private static class SingletonHolder {
        private static CowSingleton unique;
    }

    private CowSingleton(){}

    public static CowSingleton getInstance(){
        return SingletonHolder.unique;
    }

    public String cowMoo(String str)
    {
        return str;
    }
}
```

This uses the class loader to handle all the lazy initialization, thread safety, etc for you. It's completely thread safe and fast due to the fact that it doesn't need synchronization or null checks.

Comment: What about adding something like this to deal with thread safety?

     @Override
    protected Object clone() throws  CloneNotSupportedException{
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException("Clone is not allowed.");
    }

Comment: Thread safety issues occur when two threads simultaneously call CowSingleton.getInstance() - if that happens you can end up with 2 created, you can end up with 1 created but one thread sees a partially constructed one, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `static` method which can be called by the Class so remove the `new` keyword and update the code as below :

```
CowSingleton cowSingleton =  CowSingleton.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `new` keyword:

It should be

```
CowSingleton cowSingleton = CowSingleton.getInstance();
```

You are calling the `static` method `getInstance()` which delivers (and in your variant of the Singelton also create) the only object.

But please consider to "forget" the Singelton (pattern).
Erich Gamma, the autor of "Design Pattern" said, it was not a good idea to include that pattern in his book.

The reason is you cannot test it well, You cannot reset it (only with reflection).
It's often much better to have one honest global object, than a singleton.

And this all does not look fine If you have to introduce an "resetInstance()" or "resetSingleton()" method.